# Cronjob to Backup Database every day at 10pm

Tags: linux, bash, mysql, cron

I managed to setup a cronjob:

```
* 13 * * * date=`date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%s`; mysqldump -u root -pPassword1 db121 > /home/backup/xbackup_$date.sql; gzip /home/backup/xbackup_$date.sql
```

I am hoping the above will take a `mysqldump` everyday at 10pm and then save into the /home/backup directory. However, this has not worked for me.

Is the above entry correct in the crontab? If so, why wouldn't it take a backup as the command works fine when I execute it myself.

Thanks all for any help

### Update

I was reading the centos [manual for cron jobs](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-autotasks.html) and it says:

> Users other than **root** can configure
>   cron tasks by using the crontab
>   utility.

Surley, this isn't true?

Comment: On a side note: Rather then putting a plain password in there put in a mysql conf file, set the proper permissions (only readable by the correct user), and call it with `--defaults-file=/path/to/file`

Comment: One step at a time! It sounds like a great idea, but I can barley setup cron jobs!

Comment: Regarding your very last question: Users don't gain any special privileges by running something through cron.  The command is still run as if the user had executed it, it just runs at a scheduled time/interval.  So users other than root can configure tasks, they just get their own separate crontab (by default they live in /var/spool/cron/username, but it is better not to know that and just use `crontab -e` :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `crontab(5)` man page:

> ```
>    The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the  command  to  be
>    run.   The  entire  command  portion  of the line, up to a newline or %
>    character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the
>    SHELL  variable  of  the  cronfile.   Percent-signs (%) in the command,
>    unless escaped with backslash (\), will be changed into newline charac-
>    ters,  and  all  data  after the first % will be sent to the command as
>    standard input.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I escaped the %. However, no backup file was produced still! What else could be wrong. I updated my question with the edited command. I did restart crond, just incase.

Comment: @Abs: check syslog and daemon.log, and make sure to set SHELL to a shell that understands the constructs that you use. You assume it's bash, but do you know?

Comment: I've checked all logs that I can think of. I don't have a daemon.log, but I do have a cron log though? Not much in there.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the commands are not in your `$PATH`, set in in the crontab or give the full paths to the command, e.g. `/usr/bin/mysqldump`

Comment: I have changed this command to use the full path. However, the `/usr/bin/` path is in my path already within crontab: `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this

```
date='date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%s'

0 22 * * * mysqldump -u root -pPassword1 db121 > /home/backup/xbackup_`$date`.sql; gzip /home/backup/xbackup_`$date`.sql
```

Comment: I also tried this, but this didn't work as it didn't produce a file unfortunately. I have no idea what is going, it should be working!